# Redirect Website to local webserver

Tags: php, iis-7, webserver, localhost, redirect

Is it possible to redirect url browse from same network to local hosting and for other network provider to redirect to other hosting? if it is please guide me how it will done . is it done by programming using php or i need to configure server at cable net .   actually i want make website for local internet service provider he want to share vdo and files over his website but problem is that he just want only user from his network can access those files other then that they can just view website but when they try to view video they get error that your are not from  same network only user from abc network can view these files

Comment: Please try and clarify you question, it is unclear. You can redirect a url to localhost on a specific machine using .hosts file (on most OS's)

Comment: actually i want make website for local internet service provider he want to share vdo and files over his website but problem is that he just want only user from his network can access those files other then that they can just view website but when they try to view video they get error that your are not ar same network